# Is there a way to apply a color from a text string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `ListView` that is being populated by data returned from an HTTP GET Request. The request returns `String` values for an `id`, `label`, and `color`. I would like to use the `color` string that the GET Request returns to create a small colored container on the left of the `ListTile`. I have everything built but cannot figure out how to take the string returned by the GET Request and use it to specify the color.

The code for the `ListView`:

```
Widget buildList (AsyncSnapshot<ButtonsModel> snapshot) {
  return ListView.separated(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
    itemCount: snapshot.data.buttons.length,
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return ListTile(
        leading: Container(
          width: 10,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green, //Should be the color returned from the HTTP GET Request
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
        ),
        title: Text(snapshot.data.buttons[index].label),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Is the color string  the name of the color or the hexadecimal string of the color?

Comment: It's the name of the color. i.e. 'orange', 'cyan', 'purple'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to implement something like this. You would have a map of all possible color names mapped to the Color you then when you get the color name you just reference the map.

```
const Map<String, MaterialColor> kColors = {
  'Red': Colors.red,
  'Teal': Colors.teal,
  'Blue': Colors.blue,
  'Aqua': Colors.cyan,
  'Amber': Colors.amber,
  'Green': Colors.green,
  'Indigo': Colors.indigo,
  'Light Blue': Colors.lightBlue,
  'Lime': Colors.lime,
  'Orange': Colors.orange,
  'Pink': Colors.pink,
  'Purple': Colors.purple,
  'Yellow': Colors.yellow,
  'Brown': Colors.brown,
};

Widget buildList (AsyncSnapshot<ButtonsModel> snapshot) {
  return ListView.separated(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
    itemCount: snapshot.data.buttons.length,
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return ListTile(
        leading: Container(
          width: 10,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: kColors[snapshot.data.buttons[index].color],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
        ),
        title: Text(snapshot.data.buttons[index].label),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

If you want to keep your main file clean you can keep your map in a constants file.

Answer (score 0):

first the color should be an int .
here is a method to set the color so you can save it on your backend

```
int setProfileColor(Color color) {
   String colorString = color.toString();
   String valueString = colorString.split('(0x')[1].split(')')[0];
   int colorInt = int.parse(valueString, radix: 16);
   return colorInt;
}
```

then to use it all you need is to put that int inside a color widget

```
 color: Color("The int value you get from the request")
```